# Get value of Id being created in database with hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am developing an e-commerce website and integrating with payment gateway.

During this implementation, my application sending some information to the payment gateway. Along with some order information payment gateway also expecting order number which I am going to create in application.

I am using hibernate sequence generator to create an order record in my database. 
**Now I want to get this order id from my database before insertion so, that i can send that order id to the payment gateway to bind my being created order with payment transaction in the payment gateway.**

But I am not sure how I can get autogenerated id before insertion to database in hibernate ?

Is it a good way to do this or we should not create an id before insertion?

I am using hibernate 3.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using session.save(entity) or entityManager.persist(entity) method?

Comment: *I want to get this order id from my database before insertion*--nonsense, you cannot get something from DB before putting it there, otherwise integrity principle would be violated

Answer (score 0):

Using `org.hibernate.Session.save(entity)` method if you using pure hibernate or `javax.persistence.EntityManager.persist(entity)` if you using jpa will automatically set Id field in your entity. So you can get the Id after you save it on database easily.

But if you want to get the Id before you insert, using the sequece generator, it may not work fine, because if other user is doing the same operation, the id generated will be the same, you are not safe.

Answer (score 0):

As earlier indicated, you cannot fetch something from the DB before it is inserted. But you can indeed fetch the `@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=IDENTITY)` from the Hibernate `session.save()` as an Integer. For Example.

```
 public static int addPaymentRecord(String Parameter1, String Parameter2, String Parameter3, int Parameter4, int Parameter5) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        int generatedId = 0;
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            PaymentEntity pymnt = new PaymentEntity (parameter1, parameter2, parameter3, parameter4, parameter5);
            generatedId = (Integer) session.save(pymnt);
            tx.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException asd) {
            log.debug(asd.getMessage());
            if (tx != null) {
                tx.rollback();
            }
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return generatedId;
    }
```